# Datetime to ISO 8601 with time included

Tags: python, datetime, iso, iso8601

`datetime.isoformat()` returns '2018-03-24T20:25:08.698812' and `datetime.isocalendar()` returns '(2018, 12, 6)'
But what I need is the date and time in ISO format, but also in ISO calendar like this '2018-12-06T20:25:08.698812'
How do I get a datetime in both ISO format and ISO calendar?

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(d.isoformat())
print(d.isocalendar())
```

Comment: `isocalendar`?  How does that differ from `isoformat()`?

Comment: I believe because `.isocalendar()` gives ISO year, week number, and weekday @StephenRauch

Comment: isoformat just takes whatever datetime you give it and formats it in ISO format, but it doesn't actually change it to the ISO calendar. And then on the other hand, isocalender does change it to the ISO calendar, but it removes the time

Comment: @BradSolomon yes like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct format like:

#### Code:

```
def isocalendar_str(a_datetime):
    iso = a_datetime.isoformat()
    iso_cal = a_datetime.isocalendar()
    return "{:0>4}-{:0>2}-{:0>2}".format(*iso_cal) + iso[10:]
```

And if you are using Python 3.5+, you can simplify a bit with:

```
def isocalendar_str(a_datetime):
    iso = a_datetime.isoformat()
    iso_cal = a_datetime.isocalendar()
    return "{:0>4}-{:0>2}-{:0>2}{}".format(*iso_cal, iso[10:])
```

See [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for details of the new unpacking features.

#### Test Code:

```
d = dt.datetime.now()
print(d.isoformat())
print(d.isocalendar())

print(isocalendar_str(dt.datetime.now()))
```

#### Results:

```
2018-03-24T19:03:05.097419
(2018, 12, 6)
2018-12-06T19:03:05.097419
```

Comment: Nice one!, how about including iso[10:] into format? `{:0>4}-{:0>2}-{:0>2}{}".format(*iso_cal,iso[10:])`

Comment: @AntonvBR, I started there, but that made it PY3 specific, for a pretty minor gain.  I will update answer with PY3 only option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get from A to B:

```
>>> import datetime
... 
... d = datetime.datetime.now()
... print(d)
... print(d.isoformat())
... print(d.isocalendar())
... 
... yr, weeknum, weekday = map(str, d.isocalendar())
... weeknum = '0' + weeknum if len(weeknum) == 1 else weeknum
... weekday = '0' + weekday
... '-'.join((yr, weeknum, weekday)) + d.isoformat()[10:]
... 
2018-03-24 22:01:33.781735
2018-03-24T22:01:33.781735
(2018, 12, 6)
'2018-12-06T22:01:33.781735'
```

Functionally,

```
>>> def customiso(dt):
...     yr, weeknum, weekday = map(str, dt.isocalendar())
...     weeknum = '0' + weeknum if len(weeknum) == 1 else weeknum
...     weekday = '0' + weekday
...     return '-'.join((yr, weeknum, weekday)) + dt.isoformat()[10:]
... 

>>> customiso(d)
'2018-12-06T22:01:33.781735'
```

Comment: I was thinking there was some datetime function already built for this but I guess maybe not. Both of you had very quick and great answers!  not even sure what to accept actually. thanks!

Comment: You should accept @StephenRauch's in my opinion.  str formatting in his answer is more efficient than what I have here, I think.

Comment: But I wouldn't rule out there being some built-in route.  I don't know ISO beyond surface level @Frobot